# How can I compute the area of a geodesic triangle?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

How can I compute the area of a geodesic triangle in a Riemannian 2-manifold? If the Gauss curvature $K$ is constant and positive I can take the Gauss-Bonnet theorem to obtain
$A=\frac{\alpha+\beta+\gamma- \pi}{K}$. But is there also a (more) general formula in case the curvature is not constant?

Answer (score 2):

Seems it's a field of present research: [geodesic triangles](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/hokkaido-mathematical-journal/volume-30/issue-1/On-the-areas-of-geodesic-triangles-on-a-surface/10.14492/hokmj/1350911931.full).

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing:

If surface is smooth,compact etc.

Area1=$\int∫\sqrt(E G -F^2) du dv ,(u,u1,u2),(v,v1,v2)$

Area2=$\int∫\sqrt(E G -F^2) du dv , (u,u2,u3),(v,v2,v3)$

Area3=$\int∫\sqrt(E G -F^2) du dv , (u,u3,u1),(v,v3,v1)$

using $∫KdA = (α+β+γ−π)$ as a check if corner angles are given.